# Retrieve Last sent message

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Having a hard time figuring out how to do this. I have a data structure setup like (*obviously, this is not formatted correctly*):

```
Messages
---randval1
     Message: "hi"
     Date: date
     Sender: Bob
---randval2
     Message: "hey"
     Date: date
     Sender: Jim
---randval3
     Message: "hello"
     Date: date
     Sender: Bob
---randval4
     Message: "bye"
     Date: date
     Sender: Bill
```

If I want to retrieve the **last** added object to the messages node, (*which its key would be a random value*), how would I do that? My goal is to start by retrieving the last added object, and then listen for it to get updated.

Should I use a query with `child_added` then `limitToLast(1)`? My perception of child added was it would only update as a new child was added. The keys to each message child node would be random, so I can't just count up.

Answer (score 2):

First run an `.orderByChild('Date')` on the data. It would look something like this:

```
...child('Messages').orderByChild('Date').limitToLast(1)...
```